# how do I create a const URL in Dart?

Tags: dart, constants

A (constructor) method (FirebaseOptions) in Dart expects a constant String. 
Simply passing a string results in a URISyntaxException (even though it's a perfectly fine URL), so apparently I have to encode the String. 
But the String has to be const and the Uri encoder doesn't return a const String.

mucking about

Comment: Why does the `String` need to be `const`?  What was the "perfectly fine URL" you supplied?  Please post the code for what you tried along with the exact error messages that you received.

Comment: Because I use const FirebaseOptions(...,..., url_here) to initialise an app. More generally, how to make a String const from a String returning method? `const String a = methodReturnsString();`

Comment: And why must you use `const FirebaseOptions`?  And you can't make a `const` object from the result of a method call.  `const` indicates a value that can be determined at compilation time without executing any functions.

Comment: You're right, I copy pasted that in.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with `Uri` implementation due constructor of the `Uri` class is not constant.

By the way you are able to create own, constant implementation of `Uri` interface:

```dart
class MyConstUri implements Uri {
  const MyConstUri();

  //... implement or generate all necessary methods
}

const Uri reallyConstUri = MyConstUri();
```